# Overloaded template parameters - why is this example a problem?

Tags: c++, templates

I've started reading C++ Templates - the complete guide by Josuttis and Vandevoorde.
And my tiny mind is stuck.

The authors state that "You should limit your changes to the number of parameters or to specifying template parameters explicitly", using this as an example that causes problems:

```
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

// maximum of two C-strings
inline char const* const& max( char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0 ? b : a;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max( max(a,b), c);
}
```

They say that using the 3 argument version of max is an error -

```
const char * s1 = "fred";
const char * s2 = "anica";
const char * s3 = "lucas";
::max(s1, s2, s3); // ERROR
```

"because for C-strings, `max(a,b)` creates a new, temporary local value that may be returned by the function by reference.". But I compiled and ran it just fine.

Can anyone explain what the author is saying in this example?

Comment: Note that there is a difference between ::max("ab", "cd") and ::max<const char *>("ab", "cd"). This might lead to problems, especially when templates start using ::max<T>(a, b). May I suggest to specialize instead of override?

Comment: @Sjoerd - you may indeed! But I'm only on page 16... I haven't reached template specialization yet - i shall look it up :-)

Comment: @Sjoerd:  in general, you should [prefer to overload instead of specialize](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: @James Thanks for the link. I can see the problem that underlies that recommendation. Maybe do both and have the specialization call the overloaded version?

Comment: @BeeBand When you start with templates, don't worry about the difference yet: there are more important topics at the start. Once you consider writing libraries that are used by other programmers, you should start worrying about those details.

Comment: @BeeBand Now I notice that the example is copied from a book. So my comments should be directed at the writer of the book, and not at you. Apologies for reacting too quickly.

Comment: @Sjoerd - thanks, and no problem. I'm a lone C++ programmer at my current job, so I actually really appreciate *all* comments/responses to my questions (regardless of who wrote the code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the overload for "maximum of two C-strings" takes its two arguments by value, but then returns a reference to one of them.  Returning a reference to a local variable is A Bad Idea (once the local variable is destroyed when the function returns, the reference cannot be used, so it's useless).

You can fix it by taking both of the `const char*`s by const reference:

```
char const* const& max( char const* const& a, char const* const& b)
```

The original version probably does compile, but if you use the value returned from the call to `max` (which you do, since you use the result of `max(a,b)` when you call `max(max(a,b),c)`), the behavior is undefined (because you're using an object that has been destroyed).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't take a and b by reference. Returning one of them by reference means that you're returning a reference to a parameter, which is a local variable on a stack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what they are trying to say because I can't see how it would create a temporary local variable, but using templates with C-strings can fail in other unusual ways, i.e. differences between arrays of different lengths, differences between a char array and a char*, etc.

http://codeidol.com/cpp/cpp-templates/Tricky-Basics/Using-String-Literals-as-Arguments-for-Function-Templates/ acts as a good reference for these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The book's second `max` function that compares two C-strings is actually defined as

```
inline char const* max( char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0 ? b : a;
}
```

So the call `max(a,b)` inside `max(max(a,b),c)` is not the culprit. It is because `max(max(a,b),c)` is overload-resolved to `max( char const* a, char const* b)` where `a` takes the return value of `max(a,b)`. But this function returns by **value** and the 3-arg `max` returns by **reference**; therefore the error.